Perform a function only once in a method call across multiple threads in C#
I have a class from an assembly loaded at runtime that is instantiated using reflection (and therefore using a parameter-less constructor) across multiple threads (using Channels). Each thread instantiates an instance of the class and then calls Method() with a bunch of arguments.
One of the arguments contains licence keys that the plugin might need in order to use its plugins. It should apply this key only once.
My current implementation uses double-check locking:
private static bool _IsLicenceApplied;
private readonly static object _IsLicenceAppliedInitializationLock = new object();

public void Method(Keys keys, object data)
{
    if(!_IsLicenceApplied)
    {
        lock(_IsLicenceAppliedInitializationLock)
        {
            if(!_IsLicenceApplied)
            {
                Apply(keys);
                _IsLicenceApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //do the rest of the method using data
}

I've read through countless SO answers, blog posts and documentation that contain conflicting information and opinions about whether:

_IsLicenceApplied should be volatile
_IsLicenceApplied should be read and written to using the methods on the Volatile class
likewise but using the Interlocked class
I should surround the block with calls to Thread.MemoryBarrier()

A lot of these talk about the Singleton pattern and replacing such code with Lazy<T> but I need to pass the keys into the method and have the first execution deal with them. I don't think that's possible with Lazy<T>. Perhaps there's another built-in class that makes this possible?
Edit: added _IsLicenceApplied = true; after calling Apply().
Edit 2: Possible solution after reading source code of LazyInitializer (which I could use instead?):
private static bool _IsLicenceApplied;
private static object _IsLicenceAppliedInitializationLock = new object();

public void Method(Keys keys, object data)
{
    if(!Volatile.Read(_IsLicenceApplied))
    {
        lock(_IsLicenceAppliedInitializationLock)
        {
            if(!Volatile.Read(_IsLicenceApplied))
            {
                Apply(keys);
                Volatile.Write(ref _IsLicenceApplied, true);
            }
        }
    }
    //do the rest of the method using data
}


What happens if keys are applied more than once? Does Apply(keys) throw an exception then or are there other side-effects?

Is this method performance critical enough that you need the double locking? Taking an uncontested lock should be fairly fast, about 25ns. Faster than a main memory access. And removing the "double" part of the locking makes the method easier to reason about.

@Fildor In the plugins being used currently, I haven't seen any side-effects. Are you implying that what's there would be "safe enough"?

Acquiring a lock has both acquire and release semantics. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Memory-model.md#order-of-memory-operations In other words reading the variable inside the lock is guaranteed to repeat the read.

@JonasH no, it's not that critical. If threads have to queue up to get a clean read of a Boolean value (which I assume is also on the order of nanoseconds) that would be fine.

Why do you think Lazy<T> won't work? That Method could be static itself and the initialization method of Lazy could refer to static fields with the keys. Or it could be a lambda capturing the arguments. Do you expect to call the method with different keys during the application's execution?

The order you write to _IsLicenceApplied, compared to any other fields, is also important. You don't want a thread to skip the lock if the Apply method hasn't quite finished writing everything to memory yet.

@JeremyLakeman the "Examples and common patterns" section at the bottom of that documentation I think answers my question: the Singleton pattern example is there without volatile.

_IsLicenceApplied needs to be volatile because whoever is using the result of Apply has to be synchronized with whoever wrote true in it, if it is not volatile then you can read true but not get the rest of the data written by whoever wrote true, in other words volatile is not needed to read _IsLicenceApplied correctly, but it is needed to read whatever is depending on it correctly.

@JeremyLakeman I've updated the post to include flipping _IsLicenceApplied after Apply().

"Are you implying" - not really, but that would be a throttle for me how much effort I put into that. If locking always is 0 to nearly none effort, I'd just do it until it becomes a problem.

Every thread that observes a false will try to enter the lock. One thread will enter the lock first, double check that the variable is still false and run the Apply method. A volatile write to _IsLicenceApplied will ensure that any changes made by Apply are written to memory, before any other thread can observe a true, skip the lock and read an invalid value that hasn't been flushed yet. But since you haven't included the code of the Apply method, I can't tell you if that is required or not. Though I do think that situation is unlikely, it might technically be possible.

@DanDef the reason Singleton doesn't use volatile is that C# guarantees that static fields and static constructors are called once before any instance is created. You aren't talking about static type initialization here

i don't think exposing double checked locking to the code is a good idea, and Lazy<T> seems to have a thread-safe mode that you should use, so maybe whatever Apply is doing can be packaged into an object that gets constructed lazily in a thread-safe way ? it is likely still doing double checked locking under the hood, but you shouldn't worry about it, you generally shouldn't be exposing synchronization primitives.

Your first implementation, without using the Volatile, is incorrect. It allows the possibility of a compiler optimization that could cause a thread to continue before the completion of the Apply(keys) invocation. This possibility is remote, mostly theoretical, but nevertheless this implementation would be disqualified as incorrect by any reviewer who considers absolute correctness to be a non-negotiable requirement.
The second implementation, with the use of Volatile, is correct. Nevertheless it has the behavior of the LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized API, of which I am not a big fan. The questionable behavior emerges in case the Apply(keys) fails repeatedly, in which case all waiting threads will retry the execution one by one, resulting potentially to accumulated long delays. My preference is to propagate the error of the failed execution to all threads that are currently waiting. This way no thread is going to wait for longer than the duration of a single invocation. Below is a SingleExecution class with this behavior:
/// <summary>
/// Represents a synchronous operation that is invoked on demand only once, unless
/// it fails, in which case it is retried as many times as needed until it succeeds.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// In case of failure the error is propagated to the invoking thread,
/// as well as to all other threads that are currently waiting for the execution.
/// </remarks>
public class SingleExecution
{
    private volatile Task _task;

    public void EnsureInvoked<TArg>(Action<TArg> action, TArg arg)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action);
        Task capturedTask = _task;
        if (capturedTask is null)
        {
            Task newTask = new(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    action(arg);
                    _task = Task.CompletedTask;
                }
                catch
                {
                    _task = null;
                    throw;
                }
            });
            capturedTask = Interlocked
                .CompareExchange(ref _task, newTask, null) ?? newTask;
            if (ReferenceEquals(capturedTask, newTask))
                newTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        capturedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

This implementation is a modified version of the AsyncLazy class that I have posted here.
The same principle regarding handling exceptions, albeit with a different implementation, has been employed in a LazyWithRetry class that I've posted here.
Usage example:
private readonly SingleExecution _applyKeysExecution = new();

public void Method(Keys keys, object data)
{
    _applyKeysExecution.EnsureInvoked(k => Apply(k), keys);

    //...
}

